# If the phone rings while playing in background mode

Tags: ios, ios5, background, mpmovieplayercontroller, multitasking

I'm making an iphone app(Live radio app).

My app is supported background mode.

But, if the phone rings when radio app is playing in background mode, my app stop with errors .

```
MP AVAudioSessionDelegateMediaPlayerOnly end interruption. Interruptor <Phone> category <completed> resumable <0>,  _state = 6
MP endInterruptionFromInterruptor :: resuming playback
```

So, I modified my code, but useless.

I'll add my code. Please tell me my faults. Thanks.

AppDelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, AVAudioSessionDelegate>

@property (assign, nonatomic) UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask;  
... ... 

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
      bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you.
        // stopped or ending the task outright.
        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    // Start the long-running task and return immediately.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // Do the work associated with the task, preferably in chunks.

        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });
} 

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{ 
    bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{        
        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid; 
    }];     
}
```

viewController.m

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];  
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
[moviePlayer setContentURL:... m3u8];
[moviePlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this:
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];